# Update message with select menu in Discord.js v14

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Discord.js Version: 14.6.0

I am currently working with select menu. When I interacted with the menu, supposing there should be edits on the message, and it does. The problem I'm currently having is the reset of the select menu. Every time I have interacted with the menu, the menu itself reset to it default setting.

Expected Output: (Having checkmark on the selected item and with the originally message edited)
[image: 1]

Current Output: (Having original message edited but the menu is resetted)
[image]

I can only get either **replying a new message and then have the menu working fine** OR **updating the original bot message but a resetted menu bar**. Below I'm inserting the code I'm using. Let me know if you need more information.

index.js:

```js
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
// ... Command Handler here
})
```

test.js:

```js
    const row = new Discord.ActionRowBuilder()
        .addComponents(new Discord.SelectMenuBuilder()
            .setCustomId('test')
            .setPlaceholder('test 1')
            .setMinValues(1)
            .setMaxValues(1)
            .addOptions(
                {
                    label: 'test 1',
                    value: 'first_option'
                },
                {
                    label: 'test 2',
                    value: 'second_option'
                }
            ))

    const testEmbed = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle('Testing')

    interaction.reply({ embeds: [testEmbed], components: [row] })
```

selectMenu.js:

```js
    const Embed = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle('Testing 2')
    interaction.update({ embeds: [Embed] })
```

PS: The image of Expected Output is not perfect since I cannot do what I want. Imagine I want an edited message like the second photo and the select menu like the first photo.

Comment: What is interaction?

Comment: @Vulwsztyn what you don't understand?

Comment: What is the value of variable `interaction`

Comment: from event listener `interactionCreate`. Edited on the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the boolean `default` on one of the menu options to true, then it will be highlighted.
So if you want to highlight the first option it would be

```js
const row = new Discord.ActionRowBuilder()
.addComponents(new Discord.SelectMenuBuilder()
    .setCustomId('test')
    .setPlaceholder('test 1')
    .setMinValues(1)
    .setMaxValues(1)
    .addOptions(
        {
            label: 'test 1',
            value: 'first_option',
            default: true
        },
        {
            label: 'test 2',
            value: 'second_option'
        }
    )
);
```

If you would want to highlight the second option it would be

```js
const row = new Discord.ActionRowBuilder()
.addComponents(new Discord.SelectMenuBuilder()
    .setCustomId('test')
    .setPlaceholder('test 1')
    .setMinValues(1)
    .setMaxValues(1)
    .addOptions(
        {
            label: 'test 1',
            value: 'first_option'
        },
        {
            label: 'test 2',
            value: 'second_option',
            default: true
        }
    )
);
```

Comment: Alright you solved my another concern that I didn't mention. But stills, the select menu rolls back to its initial states after interacting with it. Have a look on the demonstrate video: https://youtube.com/shorts/ddYWm8jvyrM?feature=share

Comment: Because normally if I do `interact.reply` this will just fine, but not with `interact.update`

Comment: you would do interaction.message.edit

Comment: `interaction.message.edit` doesn't help. The menu still resets and it returns interaction failed

Comment: you have to also add `interaction.deferUpdate()` so it doesnt say "Interaction failed"